# Python with Turbogears2 : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'DONE'

Tags: python, python-module, turbogears2

I'm installing a project. I run theses commands but the 4th always give me this error...

- python setup.py develop
- python setup.py bdist_egg (create .egg)
- paster setup-app development.ini (create devdata.db)
- paster shell development.ini

  ```
  (tg2) root@istc-test:/var/www/tg2/tg2# paster shell development.ini
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/var/www/tg2/bin/paster", line 11, in <module>
      sys.exit(run())
    File "/var/www/tg2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 102, in run
      invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
    File "/var/www/tg2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 141, in invoke
      exit_code = runner.run(args)
    File "/var/www/tg2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 236, in run
      result = self.command()
    File "/var/www/tg2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylons/commands.py", line 499, in command
      request_id = int(tresponse.body)
  ```

  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'DONE'

I really dont know what to do... when I `import paste.script.command` it works

Thank you for your help

Comment: Your `run()` command is returning the string `DONE`, but it's expected to return a number to be used as operating system exit status. (By convention, when a use case is successful that number should be `0`; errors should be assigned 7-bit-clean integer values).

Comment: Yes I totally agree, but this is module file, not my code...


'PasteScript==2.0.2','console_scripts','paster'
__requires__ = 'PasteScript==2.0.2'
import re
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('PasteScript==2.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'paster')()
    )

Comment: `python setup.py develop` in what source tree? There's more needed to reproduce this than just what's given in your question. The string `DONE` isn't present in the PasteScript source tree, so it's clearly not coming *just* from there. One of its dependencies, maybe, but tracking that down will be easier with a [mcve].

Comment: what is source three ? I'm in python 2.7 and here is my setup.py file :

name='istc',
    version='0.3',
    description='',
    author='',
    author_email='',
    #url='',
    install_requires=[
        "TurboGears2 >= 2.0b7",
        "Catwalk >= 2.0.2",
        "Babel >=0.9.4",
        "toscawidgets >= 0.9.7.1",
        "zope.sqlalchemy >= 0.4 ",
        "repoze.tm2 >= 1.0a4",
        ],
    setup_requires=["PasteScript >= 1.7"],
    paster_plugins=['PasteScript', 'Pylons', 'TurboGears2', 'tg.devtools'],

Comment: "in what source tree" meaning *yours*. If creating that `setup.py` is both necessary and sufficient to reproduce the bug, [edit] it into your question (after testing the above condition to be true).

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing a TurboGears project prior to 2.3 the dependency management was mostly demanded to the project itself and you were required to use a private index to have reproducible installs of the project.

Make sure you install your environment with `$ easy_install -i http://www.turbogears.org/2.2/downloads/current/index tg.devtools` and only **after** you run `python setup.py develop` in your project. Otherwise you will end up with an environment that has totally incompatible packages.

*NOTE: Replace 2.2 with 2.1 if you need a prior TG version for your project to work*